# Replace number in a string by bracketed number Python

Tags: python, string, replace

I have a string like this:

```
s = k0+k1+k1k2+k2k3+1+12
```

I want to convert this, such that every number, which follows a letter (`k` here) becomes surrounded by square  brackets:

```
k[0]+k[1]+k[1]k[2]+k[2]k[3]+1+12
```

What is a good way to do that?

What I tried: Use `replace()` function 4 times (but it cannot handle numbers not followed by letters).

Comment: You'll probably have to parse the string char by char or use a regex.

Comment: @ForceBru regex is the best way to go for sure

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is one option using `re` module with regex `([a-zA-Z])(\d+)`, which matches a single letter followed by digits and with `sub`, you can enclose the matched digits with a pair of brackets in the replacement:

```
import re
s = "k0+k1+k1k2+k2k3+1+12"

re.sub(r"([a-zA-Z])(\d+)", r"\1[\2]", s)
# 'k[0]+k[1]+k[1]k[2]+k[2]k[3]+1+12'
```

---

To replace the matched letters with upper case, you can use a lambda in the replacement positions to convert them to upper case:

```
re.sub(r"([a-zA-Z])(\d+)", lambda p: "%s[%s]" % (p.groups(0)[0].upper(), p.groups(0)[1]), s)

# 'K[0]+K[1]+K[1]K[2]+K[2]K[3]+1+12'
```

Comment: Thanks. Just one query: While substituting, can you make the preceding letter in capital case (`K[0]+K[1]+K[1]K[2]+K[2]+K[3]+1+12`)?

Comment: You can use a lambda to convert the matched letters. Updated the answer with an option to do this.

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
s = re.sub('([a-z]+)([0-9]+)', r"\1" + '[' + r"\2" + ']', s)
```